# How to inherit from multiple base classes in Java?

Tags: java, multiple-inheritance

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Cheat single inheritance in Java !!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70537/cheat-single-inheritance-in-java)
>   [Why is Multiple Inheritance not allowed in Java or C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995255/why-is-multiple-inheritance-not-allowed-in-java-or-c)
>   [Multiple Inheritance in java.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262447/multiple-inheritance-in-java)

I know that we can use interfaces to inherit from multiple classes but is it possible to inherit the state as well?
How can I inherit methods with definitions from 2 classes and have them in a third class in Java?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262447/multiple-inheritance-in-java, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038314/alternative-of-multiple-inheritance-in-java, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995255/why-is-multiple-inheritance-not-allowed-in-java-or-c, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70537/cheat-single-inheritance-in-java, etc, etc.

Comment: Those other questions are not duplicates IMO.  Those questions ask *why* there is no multiple inheritance.  This question asks how to get around it -- with suitable answers provided that the other questions do not provide.

Answer (score 28):

Multiple inheritance is not allowed in Java. Use delegates and interfaces instead

```
public interface AInterface {
        public void a();
}
public interface BInterface {
    public void b();
}

public class A implements AInterface {
    public void a() {}
}
public class B implements BInterface {
    public void b() {}
}

public class C implements AInterface, BInterface {
    private A a;
    private B b;

    public void a() {
        a.a();
    }
    public void b() {
        b.b();
    }
}
```

Since Java 8 it's possible to use [Default Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) in Interfaces.

Answer (score 26):

Short answer: You can't. Java only has multiple inheritance of interfaces.

Slightly longer answer: If you make sure the methods you care about are in interfaces, then you can have a class that implements the interfaces, and then delegates to instances of the "super classes":

```
interface Noisy {
  void makeNoise();
}


interface Vehicle {
  void go(int distance);
}

class Truck implements Vehicle {
  ...
}

class Siren implements Noisy {
  ...
}

class Ambulance extends Truck implements Noisy {
  private Siren siren = new Siren();

  public makeNoise() {
    siren.makeNoise();
  }

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can not, Java doesn't support multiple inheritance. What you could do is composition.

Answer (score 2):

Java explicitly disallows multiple inheritance of implementation.  You're left with using interfaces and composition to achieve similar results.

Comment: Which Laurence has provided a great example of :)