# Android Java Extends

Tags: java, android

Hi to all. I have this problem, I created an activity (this activity is called Activity1).
 Activity1 runs a second activity (this activity is called Activity2), `public class Activity2 extends Activity1  {  }`
Now I want to implement the function `onListItemClick()`, but to use this function, I  must use  `extends ListActivity`, but if I write `public class Activity2 extends Activity1 extends ListActivity  {  }`, I have this error:

> Syntax error on token "extends", implements expected

Where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using ListActivity and onListItemClick() use activity with listView added in view and ListView.setItemClickListener() ;

Answer (score 2):

You can't extend two classes in Java. It's not clear why you believe you need to extend either or both of `Activity1` and `ListActivity`, but you won't be able to do so. (Of course if `Activity1` already extended ListActivity, you'd just have to extend `Activity1`...)

You should consider *why* you want to extend `Activity1`, and potentially use composition instead - make both `Activity1` and `Activity2` *use* an instance of the same third type which contains information and logic common to both.

Answer (score 0):

In java you can not extend two classes. If you want you, can implement multiple interfaces and extend a single class by using `class A extends B implements C,D`

Answer (score 0):

You can not extend from two classes in java. Refer to following discussion which are almost similar:
[How to inherit from multiple base classes in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031759/how-to-inherit-from-multiple-base-classes-in-java)